# Brauer groups of a local ring and of its residue field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, brauer-groups

This is a question of DeMeyer (see the last paragraph of [1]):

> What's an example of a local ring $A$ with residue field $k$ such that the restriction map on Brauer groups $\varphi : \operatorname{Br}(A) \to \operatorname{Br}(k)$ is not surjective?

*Thoughts*:

1. If $A$ is henselian (e.g. complete), then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism (see [2], IV, Corollary 2.13).
2. If $A$ contains $k$, then $\varphi$ is a split surjection.
3. If $k$ is a finite field, then $\operatorname{Br}(k) = 0$.

*References*:

[1] DeMeyer, "The Brauer group of polynomial rings", Pacific Journal of Mathematics, vol. 59, no. 2 (1975)

[2] Milne, *Etale Cohomology*, Princeton University Press, 1980

Comment: What about the easiest case not falling into 1-3, which I think is the localization of a curve over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ at a generic point in the special fiber?

Comment: Do we know if $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: It's not injective in general -- for example, the residue field of $A = \mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ is $\mathbf{F}_{p}$ so $\varphi$ is the zero map. We can compute $\operatorname{Br}(\mathbf{Z}_{(p)})$ using e.g. Theorem 3.6.4 and the class field theory exact sequence eqn (12.1) of [this](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~anskor/brauer.pdf). Thus in particular $\operatorname{Br}(\mathbf{Z}_{(p)})$ has infinite $\ell$-torsion for all primes $\ell$.