# Brauer group of the Henselization

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, brauer-groups

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring and let $R^h$ be its Henselization. What can we say about the kernel and range of the map
$$
\operatorname{Br}(R) \rightarrow \operatorname{Br}(R^h)?
$$
Are there interesting situations when the map is injective? Do we know more when $R$ is a discrete valuation ring?

Comment: commenting just to link a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361961/brauer-groups-of-a-local-ring-and-of-its-residue-field) I asked (still haven't worked out Piotr's suggestion)

Comment: @‍PiotrAchinger's [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361961/brauer-groups-of-a-local-ring-and-of-its-residue-field#comment912547_361961) on @MinseonShin's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361961/brauer-groups-of-a-local-ring-and-of-its-residue-field) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380550/brauer-group-of-the-henselization#comment966675_380550).

Comment: Have you tried looking in this book? http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~anskor/brauer.pdf

Comment: @Daniel Loughran: Looked at it superficially but could not find much. Will look deeper.